# Is it possible to list files in a specified directory in Google Drive, using google drive api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

For example, in my Google Drive, I have a directory called raw_pdf, is it possible to list all the files in that directory using Google Drive API?

Comment: Are you referring to direct children of this folder, or also files contained in folders contained in this folder, and so on? Also, can you show what research you did till now / what issues have you found / what code are you currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Q paramater which is part of files.list allows you to do a [Files search](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-shareddrives)

> parents    in  Whether the parents collection contains the specified ID.

by sending something like

```
parents in 1234
```

where 1234 is equal to the file id of your raw_pdf directory

I recommend following the official [Python quick start](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) example which shows how to authenticate your application and how to use file.list you will just need to then add the q parameter to the request.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```